# Zoomed PyGTK image without scale pixbuf

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gnome

I want to display a gtk.Image with a high level of zoom, but scale the image to a new pixbuf with the gtk.gdk.Pixbuf methods waste a lot of memory and processor.

Are there some simply way to display a zoomed image?

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible with gdk, i'm afraid.

try cairo or opengl.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe GtkImageView helps: http://trac.bjourne.webfactional.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend Clutter http://www.clutter-project.org/